# Convert UTC time_t to different timezones C++ thread safe

Tags: c++, timezone

[Updated]
I am trying to find to correct way to convert a timestamp in UTC to different timezones.

The exact problem: I have timestamps in my program and its always stored in UTC so its fine. however, i have to be able to display them (actually write them to files) in different timezones according to user preferences.

I am working on linux but I would like to write pateform-independant code.
I don't want to use boost libraries (we are already using Qt which does not provide as much functions as boost for dates).
I would like to write thread-safe code
I would like to identify the timezones like US/Eastern to simplify the configuration (it is done by users and im not very confident that they would make correct use of the abbreviations like EST, CET, CEST...).

I already looked on Internet and found some more or less working code but

- most of the time it uses the **TZ** env variable which is said to be a not thread-safe method.
- It uses abbreviations for the timezone (like EST, CET...).

Could anybody indicate me a good approach?

Here is what I have now (found on Internet some days ago and modified to used my Qt library in this example).
This code is probably not thread-safe.

NEW VERSION: 
**Still not thread-safe** but it more or less do the job.
Probably not easily portable to window environment.

It handles the daylight change 
see bellow example (daylight change in Paris happens on 25 Mars 2012 at 01H00 UTC (passing from 02H00 localtime at 03H00 localtime).
It is an example to convert Timestamp from UTC to Paris (has daylight change) & Kuala_Lumpur (does not have daylight change).

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDateTime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <QDebug>

void treatTimestamp(QString timestamp,QString format);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QString format = "MM:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss";
    treatTimestamp("03:25:2012 00:59:59",format);
    qDebug()<<"---------------------";
    treatTimestamp("03:25:2012 01:00:00",format);
    return 0;
}

void treatTimestamp(QString timestamp_s,QString format)
{
    unsetenv("TZ");
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    QDateTime timestamp = QDateTime::fromString(timestamp_s, format);
    qDebug()<<"CUSTOM TS UTC:"<<timestamp.toUTC().toString(format).toStdString().c_str();;
    time_t tmp = timestamp.toUTC().toTime_t();
    setenv("TZ", ":Asia/Kuala_Lumpur", 1);
    qDebug()<<"CUSTOM TS KL:"<<QDateTime::fromTime_t(tmp).toString(format);
    setenv("TZ", "Europe/Paris", 1);
    qDebug()<<"CUSTOM TS Paris:"<<QDateTime::fromTime_t(tmp).toString(format);
    unsetenv("TZ");
}
```

Output (First : one second before the timechange, Second: one second after).

CUSTOM TS LOC: 03:25:2012 01:00:00

CUSTOM TS UTC: 03:25:2012 01:00:00

CUSTOM TS KL: "03:25:2012 09:00:00"

CUSTOM TS Paris: "03:25:2012 03:00:00"

---

CUSTOM TS LOC: 03:25:2012 03:00:00

CUSTOM TS UTC: 03:25:2012 03:00:00

CUSTOM TS KL: "03:25:2012 11:00:00"

CUSTOM TS Paris: "03:25:2012 05:00:00"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you actually want to be able to specify a timezone, or is whatever returned by the `localtime` function ok?

Comment: I want to be able to convert from UTC to any timezone (ex: I have a timestamp  in UTC in my application and i want to write it in Beijing local time in a CSV file for a chineese user and in Paris localtime for a French user)

Comment: http://silmor.de/qtstuff.tzone.php looks promising. I don't think there's anything built in to Qt, and the C libraries are pretty non-intuitive/hard to use.

Comment: Qt 5 may improve time-zone support (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11559/#63362) but I don't think anything is improved yet.

Comment: @Mat, Iam looking at what is done by silmor, it looks like interesting but its GPL code and unfortunately iam working for on a software that is not under GPL (i know its sad... i only released one useful module on gitorious).

Comment: @skyhisi: I saw this post... sad that i dont start working on it when Qt5 is fully released... 
I even tried to find this posted code in Qt5 sources but didn't find it. Maybe i was looking at the wrong place?

Comment: Can't you just take a QTime object (or a `time_t` struct) in standard time (i.e., Greenwich) and `.addSecs(3600*timeZoneOffset)` (or add those seconds manually to the struct) before converting? I know, DST is a bitch, but I'm not sure how many libraries actually get it right, especially considering that the rules for the day to switch at do sometimes change, and may depend on more than just the time zone …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11559), using QDateTime it is possible to do `dateTime.addSecs(3600*timeZoneOffset);` where dateTime is QDateTime.

According to [gmtime reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/gmtime/), there's no built-in timezone support in C library, but you can "kinda" simulate them by adding requiring offset to `tm->tm_hour`. Which won't adjust date correctly (unlike QDateTime method), by the way.

According to [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/mktime/) reference, mktime will "normalize" datetime values, so you could add time offset to tm_hour, call mktime. However, it isn't specified HOW mktime adjusts fileds of struct tm - if you say, set tm_hour to 27, will it clamp tm_hour to 23 or will set tm_hour to 3, increasing tm_day (and possibly month/year)?

If I were you, I'd simply use `QDateTime::addSecs` method.

Comment: To usethis solution i would have to compute the difference in seconds between the UTC and the timezone. Won't it be a nightmare to handle Daylight saving time (DST)/summer time ?

Comment: @Marc: It can be nightmare in any case. Last year Russian government got rid of daylight saving time. As a result, right now there's plenty of software that still "doesn't know" about new time rules and tries to apply daylight saving time, although they're no longer in effect. Nokia released cellphone updates months after the law about new time zones became active, and I'm pretty sure there are tons of PCs that still doesn't know about new time zone rules, becuase their owner never update.

Comment: @Marc: The important thing is that daylight saving time is **region** specific - it is active within certain region or country, and UTC+3 or UTC+4 doesn't automatically indicate that there is daylight saving in effect. If you want to handle daylight saving time, you'll need database of countries and their time rules, which will be pain no matter what you do. Alternatively, you could simply allow user to specify their timezone manually (UTC+-N), which will be less hassle for you and can be implemented using `QDateTime::addSecs`

Comment: @Marc: You can check DST rules [here](http://www.worldtimezone.com/daylight.html). As you can see, it'll be pain in the *** to implement, because for every country dst starts at different date.

Answer (score 0):

I give +1 to SigTerm as his answers have been constructive.
In the end i validate with users that one running process will only need 2 timezones : a specified one and the UTC one (mostly for logging).
So in the end I use this at the top of the program
    unsetenv("TZ");
    setenv("TZ", "", 1);

Then in the specific parts where i need UTC time i always call the Qt toUTC method.
It is really not satisfying but the full software is about data acquisition and the timestamp is an important part of it so i didn't want to make my own calculation in the code.
I heard that Qt5 will have an implementation of timezone manipulation similar to what exists in the boost library. Maybe ill refactor the code when it will be out,.

Comment: In the end i exactly did that too (and for the same reasons).
Iam also waiting for Qt5